# Does <'a, 'b: 'a> mean that the lifetime 'b must outlive the lifetime 'a?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to implement a builder similar to the debug [builders](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8a3f5af8c98e123247a2847c52474f42874d23fa/src/libcore/fmt/builders.rs) defined by the standard library. They are defined using structures like the following:

```
struct DebugFoo<'a, 'b: 'a> {
    fmt: &'a mut std::fmt::Formatter<'b>
}
```

Since I don't understand what the form `<'a, 'b: 'a>` means nor I can find it mentioned in the Rust book or the Rust reference (at least concerning lifetimes), I just tried to remove what I don't understand to see what happens:

```
struct DebugFoo<'a, 'b> {
    fmt: &'a mut std::fmt::Formatter<'b>
}
```

Compiling it I get this error:

```
in type `&'a mut core::fmt::Formatter<'b>`, reference has a longer 
lifetime than the data it references
```

And this note:

```
the pointer is valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the struct at 1:0
but the referenced data is only valid for the lifetime 'b as defined on
the struct at 1:0
```

It makes sense to me: `'a` and `'b` are different lifetimes so, to be on the safe side, Rust (the borrow checker?) assumes that `'a` will outlive `'b`, and throws the error.

Now I can guess that `<'a, 'b: 'a>` means that the lifetime `'b` must be longer than the lifetime `'a`. I've guessed right? Or there is more? How can I find it documented?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The colon is read "outlives", so

```
'long: 'short
```

is read "`'long` outlives `'short`".

As for an official doc on the topic, the only place I've seen it documented so far is in the [RFC on lifetime bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0192-bounds-on-object-and-generic-types.md).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you're broadly right.

A bound `<...: 'a>` means that `...` (either a type or another lifetime) needs to be able to outlive `'a`. E.g. `'b: 'a` means that "`'b` must live at least as long as `'a`" (not strictly outlives, though: they can be the same).