# What does it mean when a struct has two lifetime parameters?

Tags: rust

I'm looking at the source for clap's [`Parser`](https://docs.rs/crate/clap/2.32.0/source/src/app/parser.rs) which has the following declaration:

```
pub struct Parser<'a, 'b>
where
    'a: 'b,
{
   ...
}
```

What do the lifetime specifiers mean here? I understand that specifying a *single* lifetime parameter indicates that member references annotated with that lifetime parameter means that an instance of that struct can't outlive the lifetime of that member.

How is this declaration different?

Comment: This syntax requires that the lifetime `'a` outlives `'b`.  See also [the relevant chapter in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html#ensuring-one-lifetime-outlives-another-with-lifetime-subtyping).

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [When is it useful to define multiple lifetimes in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29861388/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Does <'a, 'b: 'a> mean that the lifetime 'b must outlive the lifetime 'a?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30768063/155423)